# JavaScript assigning numbers to data

Tags: javascript, loops

Suppose I have 10 text boxes that I want to input some text
One of them is like the following

```
<td class="dedefault">
<input type="hidden" name="RSTS_IN" value="RW">
<label for="box_id1"><span class="fieldlabeltextinvisible">BOX</span></label>
<input type="text" name="ID_IN" size="6" maxlength="5" id="box_id1">
</td>
```

The only changes of boxes are the box number
So I want to input some texts into "box[i]"

```
var x,i;
for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
     x = box_id[i];
     document.getElementById(x).value = "12345";
}
```

But it doesn't work. How can I adjust the code?

Comment: what is `box_id` and explain more about your expected output

Answer (score 0):

you don't have any `box_id` defined.

As i understand from your question you're trying to make `box_id(some number)`
You need to build the string that you can do using `string literal` or simple `string concatenation`.

```js
var x,i;
for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
     x = `box_id${i}`;
     let ele = document.getElementById(x);
     if(ele) ele.value = "12345";
}
```

```html
<td class="dedefault">
<input type="hidden" name="RSTS_IN" value="RW">
<label for="box_id1"><span class="fieldlabeltextinvisible">BOX</span></label>
<input type="text" name="ID_IN" size="6" maxlength="5" id="box_id1">
<input type="hidden" name="assoc_term_in" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="start_date_in" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="end_date_in" value="">
</td>
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how to define     box_id ... haha

Comment: @CyWu why do you want to define ? that was simply a syntax error as per the details you provided in question.

Answer (score 0):

box_id is not an array. Make it a string and append i to it.

```js
for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    
     document.getElementById('box_id'+i).value = "12345";
}
```

```html
<td class="dedefault">
<input type="hidden" name="RSTS_IN" value="RW">
<label for="box_id1"><span class="fieldlabeltextinvisible">BOX</span></label>
<input type="text" name="ID_IN" size="6" maxlength="5" id="box_id1"/><input type="text" name="ID_IN" size="6" maxlength="5" id="box_id2"/><input type="text" name="ID_IN" size="6" maxlength="5" id="box_id3"/><input type="text" name="ID_IN" size="6" maxlength="5" id="box_id4"/><input type="text" name="ID_IN" size="6" maxlength="5" id="box_id5"/><input type="text" name="ID_IN" size="6" maxlength="5" id="box_id6"/><input type="text" name="ID_IN" size="6" maxlength="5" id="box_id7"/><input type="text" name="ID_IN" size="6" maxlength="5" id="box_id8"/><input type="text" name="ID_IN" size="6" maxlength="5" id="box_id9"/><input type="text" name="ID_IN" size="6" maxlength="5" id="box_id10"/>
</td>
```